# Django + celery - why my periodic task in not running?

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I'm working in a periodic task using django + celery. My project has django-celery==3.1.17, the broker used is Redis and it is working.

In my settings file:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
    'delivery_send': {
        'task': 'delivery.tasks.DeliverySendTask',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=1),
        'args': [],
    },
}

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'delivery.tasks.DeliverySendTask': {
        'queue': 'periodic_tasks',
        'routing_key': 'periodic_tasks'
    }, 
}
```

There are more celery settings, but I guess these two are the most relevant for this question.

The task:

```
class DeliverySendTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        logger.info('executing task!')     
        from .models import Dispatch
        Dispatch.objects.all().delete()
```

Then I run `python manage.py celery beat` and see in the console

```
[2016-06-23 14:32:01,230: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task delivery_send (delivery.tasks.DeliverySendTask)
```

But the delete is never actually executed. What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you running celery worker `python manage.py celery worker -l info`?

Comment: @RaviKumar now the task executed. The thing I was missing was initiating the worker properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

celery beat does not execute tasks. Only schedule tasks into queue. `celery worker` executes tasks.

To execute tasks periodically you have to start both `celery beat` and `celery worker`.

```
python manage.py celery beat
python manage.py celery worker
```

Comment: it is similar as `python manage.py celery worker -A helloapp --beat`

Comment: The above command gives error, saying "Unknown command: 'celery'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage."

Answer (score 2):

Install celery too. Then dont run it with manage.py. Run it like this:

```
celery -A your_app_name worker -l info -B -E
```

so without python manage.py